# DocuSign completion url

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm working with this example for sending a document for signing through email

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/master/request_sig_via_email/request_sig_via_email.php

I've been reading through the API documentation and haven't been able to find anything about being able to set a specific URL to redirect to when the recipient has completed the signing ceremony.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the return url is used with embedded signing (recipient view) workflows where you host the signing ceremony in your website or app then need to redirect to a specific page once the recipient has completed their actions.

Having said that, you can still control the redirect when your signers are remote signers (ie initiating through email). You can edit this in your branding profile, in the new DocuSign UI do:

1. From the Profile menu **Go To Admin**.
2. Select **Branding** page from Account section.
3. Select **Configure Your URLs** to edit specific return URLs.